# Python Deserialize ViewState

Tags: python, asp.net, serialization, deserialization, viewstate

I am writing a program to decode edit and re-encode ViewState in python. I have successfully been able to find view state and decode the base64 encoded string, but became stuck trying to deserialize it. Is there a way to deserialize view state using python *without* using a windows-only python library? I wand my program to be able to run it on any computer with python installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently released a library that does .NET viewstate decoding, feel free to try it out https://github.com/yuvadm/viewstate/

Sample usage:

```
>>> from viewstate import ViewState
>>> base64_encoded_viewstate = '/wEPBQVhYmNkZQ9nAgE='
>>> vs = ViewState(base64_encoded_viewstate)
>>> vs.decode()
('abcde', (True, 1))
```